# Custom Metric for ADR and FAR in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I need to define a custom metric in keras with a tensorflow  backend, to get ADR and FAR metrics, where:

- ADR is the ratio between the number of correctly detected elements of Class 1 and the total number of elements in Class 1.
- FAR is the ratio between the number of Class 0 elements that are incorrectly classified as Class 1 elements and the total number of Class 0 elements.

For now, I have been able to compute the total number of elements on each class:

```
def false_rates(y_true, y_pred):
    total_1 = K.sum(tf.cast(tf.equal(y_true, 1), 'int32'))
    total_0 = K.sum(tf.cast(tf.equal(y_true, 0), 'int32'))
    # [...]
```

Now, for each index `i` in the tensor, I need to count how many:

- `y_true[i] == 1 and y_pred[i] == 1` for ADR
- `y_true[i] == 0 and y_pred[i] == 1` for FAR

But I have no idea how to do this with tensorflow operations, the closest I got is this:

```
adr = K.sum(
        tf.cast(
            tf.equal(
                tf.add(
                    tf.cast(tf.equal(y_true, 1), 'int32'),
                    tf.cast(tf.equal(y_pred, 1), 'int32')), 2), 'int32'))

# far = ...?
```

But it doesn't seem to return anything else than 0.

Thank you for you help!

---

Edit to include the complete code:

```
# coding: utf-8
import csv
import numpy as np
import os

os.environ["KERAS_BACKEND"] = "tensorflow"

from keras import backend as K
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping, TensorBoard
from keras.layers import Convolution2D
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop, SGD
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras.preprocessing.text import one_hot

def build_model(input_shape, n1, dropout_p, n_symbols, n_sequence):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Embedding(n_symbols+1,
                        output_dim=n1,
                        input_length=n_sequence))
    model.add(LSTM(n1))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout_p))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    return model

def load_sequences(path):
    X, y = [], []
    with open(path,'r') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        for line in reader:
                X.append(line[0])
                y.append(int(line[1]))
    return np.array(X), np.array(y)

def adr_and_far(y_true, y_pred):
    total_adr = K.sum(K.tf.cast(K.tf.equal(y_true, 1), 'int32'))
    total_far = K.sum(K.tf.cast(K.tf.equal(y_true, 0), 'int32'))

    adr_idx = K.tf.equal(y_true, 1) & K.tf.equal(y_pred, 1)
    adr_idx = K.tf.reshape(K.tf.where(adr_idx), [-1])

    far_idx = K.tf.equal(y_true, 0) & K.tf.equal(y_pred, 1)
    far_idx = K.tf.reshape(K.tf.where(far_idx), [-1])

    num_adr = K.tf.shape(adr_idx)[0]  # 3
    num_far = K.tf.shape(far_idx)[0]  # 2

    return { 'total_adr': total_adr,
             'adr': num_adr / total_adr,
             'total_far': total_far,
             'far': num_far / total_far
           }

simbols = ['1','a','A','r','2','b','B','s','3','c','C','t','4','d','D','u','5','e','E','v','6','f','F','w','7','g','G','x','8','h','H','y','9','i','I','z', ',', '.', '*', '+', '0']
n_symbols = len(simbols) # dimensionality of your word vectors

max_len_sequence = 20
input_shape = (max_len_sequence, n_symbols)
n1 = 128 # From Paper
dropout_p = 0.1
loss_method = 'binary_crossentropy'

optimizer = 'adam'
model = build_model(input_shape, n1, dropout_p, n_symbols, max_len_sequence)
model.compile(loss=loss_method, optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy', adr_and_far])
```

And the error:

```
 Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1%29+Training+RNN+Single+Model.py", line 68, in <module>
    model.compile(loss=loss_method, optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy', adr_and_far])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 594, in compile
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 716, in compile
    metric_result = metric_fn(y_true, y_pred)
  File "1%29+Training+RNN+Single+Model.py", line 43, in adr_and_far
    adr_idx = K.tf.reshape(K.tf.where(adr_idx), [-1])
TypeError: select() takes at least 3 arguments (1 given)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you just need to count?

```
y_true = tf.constant([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1])
y_pred = tf.constant([1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0])

adr_idx = tf.equal(y_true, y_pred) & tf.equal(y_true, 1)
adr_idx = tf.reshape(tf.where(adr_idx), [-1]) # [0, 1, 6]

far_idx = tf.equal(y_true, 0) & tf.equal(y_pred, 1) 
far_idx = tf.reshape(tf.where(far_idx), [-1])  # [3, 4]

num_adr = tf.shape(adr_idx)[0]  # 3
num_far = tf.shape(far_idx)[0]  # 2

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    a, b = sess.run([num_adr, num_far])
```

use keras 1.2.1 with tensorflow version 0.11
I think the reason is different shape
The shape of y_true is `(?, ?)` and shape of y_pred is `(?, 1)` ?

```
def adr_and_far(y_true, y_pred):
    total_adr = K.sum(K.tf.cast(K.tf.equal(y_true, 1), 'int32'))
    total_far = K.sum(K.tf.cast(K.tf.equal(y_true, 0), 'int32'))

    adr_idx = K.tf.equal(y_true, 1) & K.tf.equal(y_pred, 1)
    adr_idx = K.sum(K.tf.cast(K.reshape(adr_idx, [-1]), 'int32'))

    far_idx = K.tf.equal(y_true, 0) & K.tf.equal(y_pred, 1)
    far_idx = K.sum(K.tf.cast(K.reshape(far_idx, [-1]), 'int32'))


    return { 'total_adr': total_adr,
             'adr': adr_idx / total_adr,
             'total_far': total_far,
             'far': far_idx / total_far
           }
```

Comment: You answer seems pretty close to what I need, but everytime I try to use `tf.where` I got this `TypeError: select() takes at least 3 arguments (1 given)`

Comment: The previous error only appears when both Keras and Tensorflow are imported.

Comment: so if just import keras or tensorflow is ok? If you use tensorflow as backend, do you need to import both of them?

Comment: Sorry, I expressed myself poorly. I mean, if I import Keras, then Tensorflow will throw that error and it doesn't matters if I use `tf` (from tensorflow module) or `K.tf` (tensorflow from Keras Backend module). I also checked that Tensorflow version used by Keras is the same that when I use Tensorflow in standalone mode.

Comment: Or can you paste your code. BTW if you do  `from keras import backend as K`, do you use `k` like `k.where`, not `k.tf.where`?

Comment: I have paste the complete code so you can try to run it. I tried with `tf.where`and `K.tf.where`,  `K.where` is not defined. Thanks you so much for you interest.

Comment: Update post, can you check if it work right or just work